# Trying to figure out why my systems render times are so different

Tags: premiere

Can someone help me figure out why 1 system is rendering faster than the other.
System 1 specs 
GPU Quadro K2000
CPU Intel® Xeon® processor E3-1245 v3 3.4 3.8 8 MB 1600 MHz 4
Ram 32 GB
OS Windows 7 64bit
Facilis Terrablock with Fiber connection (used to pull footage)
rendering to a 10k rpm dedicated drive in system.
Task manager say 85% of processor is being used

System 2 specs
GPU Quadro K600
CPU Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2620 v2 2.1 15 MB 1600 MHz 6
Ram 16 GB
OS Windows 7 64bit
Facilis Terrablock with Fiber connection (used to pull footage)
rendering to a 10k rpm dedicated drive in system.
Task manager say 2% of processor is being used

Update with image
new project with new stats
The 2nd system renders this same project out in 1/2 to 1/3 the time but as the pic shows the GPU is barely being used. and system 2 uses almost not CPU still below 5%
[image]

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the second setup renders faster because it includes the by far better CPU? ;-)
2 % processor usage during rendering can't be correct, maybe the taskmanager doesn't show the correct values ...
Though the difference is very high ... does the second system per chance have a GPU with CUDA or OpenCL support that the first one doesn't have? That would explain the great difference ...

Comment: System 2 is using GPU acceleration, System 1 is using CPU rendering. GPUs, especially Quadros run many rendering tasks FAR more efficiently than a general purpose CPU. It could easily explain the difference of 83% CPU utilization and 40 minutes of render time.

Comment: They are both quaddros and both have CUDA.

Comment: That would be my initial though as well but I have made sure that both systems are using the cuda acceleration unless there is another setting I am missing with system 1 they should both be using GPU rendering.

Comment: Are you using Adobe Media Encoder for the renders or Premiere directly?  Can you post actual screen shots of your settings?

Comment: ohh and post systems are using media encoder

Comment: Hit print screen while the screen is up, open Photoshop, create a new document and hit ctrl-v to paste the contents of the clipboard in to the new image.  Save it for web.  Then, edit your question and use the Image button above the editor to add images to the post.  It will automatically upload it to imgur and link it in your question.

Comment: I have uploaded images from system 1 only as I am unable to access system 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System 2 is using GPU acceleration, System 1 is using CPU rendering.  GPUs, especially Quadros run many rendering tasks FAR more efficiently than a general purpose CPU.  It could easily explain the difference of 83% CPU utilization and 40 minutes of render time.

Note that while your system is showing only 14% CPU utilization in the screen shots, that is 100% of a single threaded process.  If the calculation isn't broken in to multiple threads, then it has to process on one core of the processor, which appears to be what is happening here.  That one core is completely maxed out.

I see you have CUDA selected as the renderer in the second screen shot, however it is not being used based on the GPU usage information.  This is probably related to a driver issue preventing Media Encoder from being able to utilize the GPU hardware.  Try updating your graphics drivers and verify that your graphics card appears on the list of supported graphics cards for CUDA support.

Comment: @Curtmcd - the only other alternative I can think of is that there is a virus or misconfiguration on the first system.  By all normal measures, the first system should significantly out perform the second and the CPU should not be nearly that high.  CPU utilization says that something is running on the CPU that shouldn't be.  Perhaps your preview is running CUDA but final render is not?

Comment: Ok I updated the photo to how it works. Heres a weird piece of info I have come across. If I use Media Encoder CC it uses the GPU up to 80% on this machine, but if I use Media Encoder CC2014 then it doesn't. And my drivers are up to date. Also the card is cuda supported